# document-wide ordered lists in ascii doctor

Tags: asciidoctor

I would like to define a new style of ordered lists in asciidoctor that is composed of a fixed uppercase letter and a counter that increments. It has to be document wide. For example

> A1. first item
>
> A2. second item
>
> some text
>
> A3. third item
>
> the flow of the text continues

The solution I came up with is as follows, which is heavy and not 100% satisfactory.

```
[horizontal]
A{counter:ol1}.:: first item
A{counter:ol1}.:: second  item

some text

[horizontal]
A{counter:ol1}.:: third  item

the flow of the text continues
```

Is there a simpler solution ? Is there a possibility at least to define a macro that would expand to `A{counter:ol1}.::`?

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of choices:

1. Create a macro in your editor that inserts the required markup (assuming that your goal is to reduce the amount of typing to achieve this effect).
2. Adjust the markup to specify a custom role and drop the counter:

```
= My document
:docinfo: shared

[horizontal, role=numbered]
A:: first item
A:: second  item

some text

[horizontal, role=numbered]
A:: third  item

the flow of the text continues
```

Then add some custom CSS, via a docinfo file (see: https://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#docinfo-file), that does the counting for you. This won't work in PDF output.

```css
body {
  counter-reset: myli;
}

.hdlist.numbered .hdlist1::after {
  content: counter(myli) ". ";
  counter-increment: myli;
}
```